# How to delete a latex macro in the text but not its argument

Tags: macros

I a newbie in LaTeX. I have the following problem.

How to delete a LaTeX macro in the text but not its argument? In particular, how to  replace a macro in the text, e.g

```
\command1{text_inside_the_brackets}
```

with the text inside the brackets? (the text in the brackets are different).

It is very time consuming to replace it manually, anybody has an idea how to make it faster?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Do you mean something like `\renewcommand{\command1}[1]{#1}` in the preamble?

Comment: My immediate thought would be to `\def\command#1{#1}` right before `\begin{document}`.  That way you don't need to go through and delete it.

Comment: all, Example,
This what I have:        agent\cx{s} might be coupled \cx{via the output of other agents}.       
   What I want is just to delete \cx{} automatically, so that it will look like:        of agents might be coupled via the output of
other agents. The objective is to find decentralized controllers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about TeX or friends.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\command1{\([^}\\{]*\)}/\1/g' <filename.tex> > filename-new.tex
```

One thing to note is that regular expressions are not all the same and the correct syntax depends on the command you are using. So the syntax which is correct in one editor may not be identical to that in another. Kile, for example, uses a different syntax from vim.

The above command will catch *all* instances of `\mycommand1{}` even if they are on the same line. (This is what the `g` at the end does.)

Like Tobi's code, it will *not* replace something like

```
\mycommand1{here is some text} which I wrote earlier \mycommand2{like this}
```

with

```
here is some text} which I wrote earlier \mycommand2{like this
```

but instead with

```
here is some text which I wrote earlier \mycommand2{like this}
```

which is probably what you want. It will, however, catch things like

```
\mycommand1{here-is-some-hyphenated-text}
```

but it will still ignore nested commands such as `\mycommand1{\mycommand2{hi}}`. `[^}\\{]` tells it to ignore chains which contain `{` or `\` between `{` and `}` but to allow anything else in the scope of a single `{...}`.

It is important to check the results are what you expect. Therefore, the output is sent to a new copy of the file rather than overwriting the original. That way, you can easily revert if the results are not what you expected.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to change the code and not the resulting PDF. With regular expressions you can do an advanced search and replace. The expression

```
\\[A-z]*\{([A-z0-9 ]*)\}
```

combined with the replacement

```
\1
```

Will replace *all* macros in a text like

```
Text \macro{Text 1} \command{Text 2} Text
```

to

```
Text Text 1 Text 2 Text
```

as long as the argument appears in a single line and contains only letters, numbers and spaces. If you want only a certain macro to be replaced change `\\[A-z]*` to `\\macroname`.

**A closer look at the search term**

```
\\            backslash
[A-z]*        only letters, * = of any number
\{            opening brace
  (             begin a group
  [A-z0-9 ]*      letters, numbers and spaces
  )             end group
\}            closing brace
```

A group can be access by `\<n>` in the replacement text.

---

Some editors provide a shortcut to delete a singe command but not it’s argument. In TeXstudio on a Mac it is <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> for example.

Comment: Note that this will replace *all* simple macros - not just `\command1`.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks! I added this note to my answer.