# Delete a macro leaving the argument intact

Tags: macros, texstudio

I'm using TeXstudio and I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut that deletes a generic macro while leaving the macro argument itself intact *in the .tex source*.

For example I want to make a text normal by removing the boldface macro: from
`\textbf{generic text}` to `generic text`, all in one simple shortcut.

I've seen two similar questions, but they weren't answering my specific question: [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162837/how-to-delete-a-latex-macro-in-the-text-but-not-its-argument) was concerning about the UNIX shell and was labeled as off- topic, the [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519519/automatically-delete-a-macro-using-texstudio) was about removing the macro effect *only in the PDF*, while I want to remove the macro in the .tex source.

Comment: You can try a regex like this `\\textbf{([^}]*)}` => `\1` (Live example https://regex101.com/r/QDAT02/2)

Comment: Thank you very much! But I would like a faster way to do the replacement, so do you know if there's a way to extend this to all the macros (`\textit{}`, `\emph{}` and many others) and to make a custom shortcut for this?

Comment: Well, you can easily generalize to `\\[A-z]+{([^}]*)}` => `\1`, although this is likely to match way too much.  I don't know whether you can save searches in TeXstudio.

Comment: @HenriMenke thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given input `\textbf{...}` (or any one-argument commands),

- put cursor in command name `\textbf`, then
- click menu item "Idefix -> Erase Word/Cmd/Env", which can be assigned a shortcut in "Configure TeXstudio -> Shortcuts".

Finally you get `...` from `\textbf{...}`.

Comment: What editor are you using? Mine does not have any menu item "Idefix".

Comment: @PeterWilson the editor is TeXstudio

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z thank you! It's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to the whole document?